# QAbstractTableModel and emit dataChanged for a single row

Tags: c++, qt, row, onchange, qabstracttablemodel

I derived a model from QAbstractTableModel and now I want to notify, that the data of a whole row has been changed. If for example the data of a row with index 5 is changed (4 columns), than using the following code works as expected.

```
emit dataChanged(index(5,0), index(5, 0));
emit dataChanged(index(5,1), index(5, 1));
emit dataChanged(index(5,2), index(5, 2));
emit dataChanged(index(5,3), index(5, 3));
```

But if I try to *achieve the same* with only one emit, ALL columns of ALL rows in the view are updated.

```
emit dataChanged(index(5, 0), index(5, 3));
```

What I am doing wrong here?

### Minimal example (C++11, QTCreator 4.7.1, Windows 10 (1803), 64 Bit)

**demo.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>

class Demo : public QAbstractTableModel
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QTimer * t;
public:
  Demo()
  {
    t = new QTimer(this);
    t->setInterval(1000);
    connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()) , this, SLOT(timerHit()));
    t->start();
  }

  QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
  {
    int c = index.column();
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
      QString strTime = QTime::currentTime().toString();
      if (c == 0) return "A" + strTime;
      if (c == 1) return "B" + strTime;
      if (c == 2) return "C" + strTime;
      if (c == 3) return "D" + strTime;
    }
    return QVariant();
  }

  int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const override { return 10; }
  int columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const override { return 4; }
private slots:
  void timerHit()
  {
    //Works
    emit dataChanged(index(5,0), index(5, 0));
    emit dataChanged(index(5,1), index(5, 1));
    emit dataChanged(index(5,2), index(5, 2));
    emit dataChanged(index(5,3), index(5, 3));

    //emit dataChanged(index(5,0), index(5, 3)); // <-- Doesn't work
  }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "demo.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTreeView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QTreeView dataView;
  Demo dataModel{};
  dataView.setModel( &dataModel );
  dataView.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output for `emit dataChanged(index(5, 0), index(5, 3));`? To change all columns? To change only `index(5, 0)` and `index(5, 3)`? (This wasn't particularly clear to me from your question.)

According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged), all cells inclusive within that range will be changed.

Comment: I rephrased it in my question. I expect, that all columns in that range will be changed in the view. So that should be only column 0 - 3 from row 5 and not ALL columns of all rows of the whole model. Why are ALL columns of all rows changed in the view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem lies with certain assumptions you're making with regard the behaviour of `QTreeView` when the [`QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal is emitted.

Specifically, you assume that the view will only invoke [`QAbstractItemModel::data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) on those indexes that are specified in the signal.  That's not necessarily the case.

Looking at the source for `QAbstractItemView::dataChanged` (`Qt` 5.11.2) you'll see...

```
void QAbstractItemView::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles)
{
    Q_UNUSED(roles);
    // Single item changed
    Q_D(QAbstractItemView);
    if (topLeft == bottomRight && topLeft.isValid()) {
        const QEditorInfo &editorInfo = d->editorForIndex(topLeft);
        //we don't update the edit data if it is static
        if (!editorInfo.isStatic && editorInfo.widget) {
            QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate = d->delegateForIndex(topLeft);
            if (delegate) {
                delegate->setEditorData(editorInfo.widget.data(), topLeft);
            }
        }
        if (isVisible() && !d->delayedPendingLayout) {
            // otherwise the items will be update later anyway
            update(topLeft);
        }
    } else {
        d->updateEditorData(topLeft, bottomRight);
        if (isVisible() && !d->delayedPendingLayout)
            d->viewport->update();
    }

#ifndef QT_NO_ACCESSIBILITY
    if (QAccessible::isActive()) {
        QAccessibleTableModelChangeEvent accessibleEvent(this, QAccessibleTableModelChangeEvent::DataChanged);
        accessibleEvent.setFirstRow(topLeft.row());
        accessibleEvent.setFirstColumn(topLeft.column());
        accessibleEvent.setLastRow(bottomRight.row());
        accessibleEvent.setLastColumn(bottomRight.column());
        QAccessible::updateAccessibility(&accessibleEvent);
    }
#endif
    d->updateGeometry();
}
```

The important point is that this code behaves differently depending on whether or not the signal specifies a single `QModelIndex` -- e.g. `topLeft` is the same as `bottomRight`.  If they *are* the same then the view tries to ensure that only that model index is updated.  However, if multiple model indexes are specified then it will invoke...

```
d->viewport->update();
```

which will, presumably, result in the data for all visible model indexes being queried.

Since your implementation of `Demo::data` always returns new data based on the current time you will see the entire visible part of the view update giving the impression that the `dataChanged` signal was emitted for all rows and columns.

So the fix is really to make your data model more ``stateful'' -- it needs to keep track of values rather than simply generating them on demand.

Comment: Thanx for that answer. So in my real-world-model, when I have 500k rows inserted and mostly only one single row changes in the model, I have to call x times dataChanged instead of a single "range-call", right?!

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you emit the `dataChanged` signal specifying multiple model indexes it might update more than you specify -- but not all 500k.

Comment: I made a test for 100k elements (changing 2 columns in a single row). Result: Calling the range-method results in 3 times more calls to data() for the same viewport. Ur right, that not all data is queried, only a few times (31), but the "range-call" will call much more times the data().

Answer (score 2):

This is a genuine efficiency bug in Qt.

The Qt project is [no longer accepting changes to Qt 5](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2021-January/040798.html), so I made the change and pushed it to my fork on GitHub. You can see a fix for the issue you've encountered [here](https://github.com/ulatekh/qtbase/commit/5e56947ecd2fa7ae3951cfdfef7a2975f7fb559a).

If you want to build your own copy of 5.15.2, you may be interested in my [other fixes](https://github.com/ulatekh/qtbase/commits/5.15.2).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is what you're looking for but I'll put it up anyways.

---

Even using `emit dataChanged(...)`, you would still see that clicks/selection on rows will cause them to self-update (doing this from a Mac, so might be different).

Instead of using the `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged` signal, I will be using the [`QAbstractItemModel::setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) function.

This is my implementation of `demo.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>

class Demo : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Demo()
    {
        int cCount = columnCount(index(0, 0));
        int rCount = rowCount(index(0, 0));

        //  populate model data with *static* values
        QString strTime = QTime::currentTime().toString();

        QStringList temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < cCount; j++)
            temp.append(strTime);
        for (int i = 0; i < rCount; i++)
            demoModelData.append(temp);

        //  nothing new here
        t = new QTimer(this);
        t->setInterval(1000);
        connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()) , this, SLOT(timerHit()));
        t->start();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {

        //  tells the *view* what to display
        //      if this was dynamic (e.g. like your original strTime implementation)
        //      then the view (QTreeView in main.cpp) will constantly update
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
            return demoModelData.at(index.row()).at(index.column());    //  retrieve data from model

        return QVariant();
    }

    //  reimplemented from QAbstractTableModel
    virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) override
    {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            demoModelData[index.row()][index.column()] = value.toString();  //  set the new data

            emit dataChanged(index, index);     //  explicitly emit dataChanged signal, notifies TreeView to update by 
                                                //  calling this->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole)
        }

        return true;
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const override { return 10; }
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const override { return 4; }

private slots:
    void timerHit()
    {
        QString strTime = QTime::currentTime().toString();
        setData(index(5, 0), QVariant(strTime), Qt::DisplayRole);   //  only changes index at (row = 5, col = 0)
    }

private:
    QTimer *t;

    QList<QStringList> demoModelData;       //  stores the table model's data

};
```

Since the class is a "model", there should be some way of storing/retrieving data for display. Here, I've used a `QList<QStringList>`, but you can store data in other ways that suit you as well (e.g. a tree, QVector, QMap).

Comment: Thanx for that, but I need an answer only for the question i asked. Have I found a bug in Qt or am I misinterpreting the behavior of dataChanged?

Comment: Misinterpreting, I believe. From the documentation: `This signal [dataChanged] is emitted whenever the data in an existing item changes.`, but from your example, the signal is being emitted to change the data. (It's going the other way round, not what it's meant for. Use `setData` instead.)

Comment: My example is correct. My data changes (over time), and I tell the model that something has been changed. My question is clear I think...I believe, qt has not to update its whole view, when I told them, that the data of the columns of row with index 5 has been changed.