# How is the concept of a "parent" meaningful in a QAbstractListModel?

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel, pyside6, qabstractlistmodel

I have a subclass of `QAbstractListModel` that is the model for a QML `ListView` (using PySide6). Each row of the list has a checkbox in it, and when the user checks/unchecks a box, it updates a boolean in that row of the listmodel using my override of `setData()`, which works as expected. I also have `Button`s that should select/clear all of the checkboxes in the list.

My model subclass provides the following method to select all, which can be called when the user hits the `Button` or when other things happen in the application:

```py
def select_all(self):
    for i in range(self.rowCount()):
        row = self._rows[i]
        row['selected'] = True

        # Emitting this for each row works...
        self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(i), self.index(i), [])
        
    # ... whereas emitting just one signal for ALL rows does NOT work
    # self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0), self.index(self.rowCount()), [])
```

As you can see from the comments, I need to emit `dataChanged` for each row in order for the checkboxes in the `ListView` to be updated. Emitting the signal once and using the `topLeft` and `bottomRight` parameters ***does not*** update the state of the checkboxes in the `ListView` (but the model data ***is*** correctly updated).

According to the documentation, the `dataChanged` signal provided by `QAbstractItemModel` (and inherited by `QAbstractListModel`) has [this caveat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged):

> If the items are of the same parent, the affected ones are those between topLeft and bottomRight inclusive. If the items do not have the same parent, the behavior is undefined.

It seems likely that I'm running into the scenario where the rows in my model do NOT have the same parent, and therefore, "the behavior is undefined." I suppose that makes sense, because I never do anything to establish a parent/child relationship for any of my rows. I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142622/3684433) which implies that Qt behaves differently when the `topLeft` and `bottomRight` indices are the same. So, I would like to understand this better, and I have a few questions:

1. Am I correct that this parent concept is the reason this ***does*** work when emitted for each row and ***does not*** work for all rows?
2. Is the concept of a parent/child relationship only meaningful for tree-like models that would extend `QAbstractItemModel` instead of `QAbstractListModel`? Does it make any kind of sense for a list?
3. If it does make sense for a list, then what would be the "parent" and what would be the "child?" How would I configure a subclass of `QAbstractListModel` such that `dataChanged` can be emitted once to update multiple rows?

Thanks!

Comment: `self.index(self.rowCount())` is not a valid index: if you have 2 rows, the last row index is 1, not 2. It should be `self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0), self.index(self.rowCount() - 1), [])`

Comment: Oof. You're absolutely right. I got so caught up thinking I misunderstood how it worked that I missed that error. @musicamante, could you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the base implementation of Qt item views just updates indiscriminately the view whenever the `topLeft` and `bottomRight` indexes doesn't match (so you can just provide two "random", but still *sibling* indexes), the indexes must not only share a common parent (which for one and two dimensional models is always an invalid index), but also both *valid*.

With this line, the second index is *not* valid:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0), self.index(self.rowCount()), [])
```

This is because the indexes are always 0-based, and the index of the last row is actually `rowCount - 1`. While they theoretically are siblings, since they share the same parent (the parent of a root index is invalid, as it is the parent of an invalid index), they are not *both* valid.

So, the correct syntax is:

```
self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0), self.index(self.rowCount() - 1), [])
                                                               ^^^^
```

Note that the `roles` argument is optional and already defaults to an empty list (QVector in C++), so unless you actually want to specify the changed roles, you don't need to provide that.